# Assume that there are 5 records, each containing 2 temperatures

Tags: vb.net

Assume that there are 5 records, each containing temperature values. The first temperature value on each record represents a high temperature from weather station, and the second temperatures on each record represents a low temperature from a weather station, input these temperatures into a table TEMP (5, 2) the with high temperatures from the 5 stations in column 1 of the table, and the low temperatures of the 5 stations in column 2 of the table. After reading in all the temperatures, find and output the average high temperatures and the average low temperatures for the 5 weather stations.

I have a code that I wrote in VB.NET but its not going through. Here is the code,

```
Module Module1
   Dim TEMP(5, 2) As Integer
   Dim count As Integer
   Dim AVGHIGH As Integer
   Dim AVGLOW As Integer
   Dim i As Integer = 5
   Dim high As Integer
   Dim stations As Integer = 5
   Dim low As Integer
   Dim Totalhigh As Integer
   Dim Totallow As Integer

  Sub Main()
    Call InputArray()
    Call ComputeandOutputAverageHightempandLowtemp()
    Call OutputArray()
    Console.WriteLine("Please Press Enter")
    Console.ReadLine()
  End Sub
  Sub InputArray()


    stations = 0

    Console.WriteLine("Enter{0} temperatures, one per line ", i)
    Console.ReadLine()
    TEMP(i, 2) = "High Temperature"
    TEMP(i, 1) = Console.ReadLine()
    TEMP(i, 2) = "Low Temperature"
    TEMP(i, 2) = Console.ReadLine()

    Do While stations <= i
      stations = stations + 1

    Loop
  End Sub
  Sub ComputeandOutputAverageHightempandLowtemp()
    high = TEMP(i, 1)
    low = TEMP(i, 2)
    stations = 1
    Totalhigh = 0
    Totallow = 0
    Do While stations <= 5
     stations = stations + 1
      If high > low Then
        Totalhigh = 1 + TEMP(i, 1)
        AVGHIGH = Totalhigh / stations
      End If
      Totallow = 1 + TEMP(i, 2)
      AVGLOW = Totallow / stations
    Loop
    Console.WriteLine("High: " & Totalhigh)
    Console.WriteLine("Low: " & Totallow)
    Console.WriteLine("average high temperature: " & AVGHIGH)

  End Sub
  Sub OutputArray()
    stations = 0
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("The number in the list are: ")
    Do While (stations <= 5)
      stations = stations + 1
      Console.WriteLine(TEMP(i, 1) & "")
      Console.WriteLine(TEMP(i, 2) & "")
    Loop

  End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'program does not go through.' Do you receive and error or nothing happens?   In the InputArray sub - you have a do while loop that simply adds 1 to stations until it is 5, after it executes the block above once.

Comment: Please explain EXACTLY what you expect to happen and EXACTLY what does happen.

Answer (score 0):

Module Module1

```
Dim Temp(5, 2)
Dim HTemp As String
Dim LTemp As String
Dim TotHTemp As Integer
Dim TotLTemp As Integer
Dim AvgHTemp As Integer
Dim AvgLTemp As Integer
Dim Record As Integer
Dim Row As Integer
Dim TotRow As Integer
Dim Accum As Integer
Dim Count As Integer

Sub Main() 'Overall (A000)

    Console.Write("Please Enter the total number of Stations that you want to process( High Temp and Low Temp: ")

    Record = Console.ReadLine()

    TotRow = Record
    Row = TotRow - 1

    Do While Row >= 0

        Console.Write("Please Enter high Temperature: ")
        HTemp = Console.ReadLine()


        Console.Write("Please Enter Low Temperature: ")
        LTemp = Console.ReadLine()

        TotHTemp = TotHTemp + HTemp
        TotLTemp = TotLTemp + LTemp


        Call Input()

    Loop
    Call comput()

    Call Output()

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Sub Input() '(B000)

    Temp(Row, 0) = HTemp
    Temp(Row, 1) = LTemp
    Row = Row - 1


End Sub

Sub comput() '(B010)
    AvgHTemp = TotHTemp / TotRow
    AvgLTemp = TotLTemp / TotRow

End Sub



Sub Output() '(B020)

    Console.WriteLine() ' for spacing 

    Dim format As String = "{0,-25}{1,-25}{2}"
    Console.WriteLine(format, "Record", "High Temp", "Low Temp")

    Accum = 1
    Count = Accum
    Row = 0
    Do While Row < TotRow

        Console.WriteLine(format, Count, Temp(Row, 0), Temp(Row, 1))
        Call Counter()

        Row = Row + 1

    Loop

    Console.WriteLine() ' for Space
    Console.WriteLine(" Avg of high Temperatues =: " & AvgHTemp)
    Console.WriteLine(" Avg of Low temperatures =: " & AvgLTemp)


End Sub
Sub Counter() '(C000)

    Accum = Accum + 1
    Count = Accum

End Sub
```

End Module